# Access Gitlab container via https

Tags: docker, https, gitlab

I had a Docker container created in Powershell using the commands shown.

```
docker run --detach 
  --hostname gitlab.example.de 
  --ip 192.168.178.35 
  --publish 443:443 --publish 80:80 --publish 22:22 
  --name gitlab 
  --restart always 
  --volume $env:GITLAB_HOME/config:/etc/gitlab 
  --volume $env:GITLAB_HOME/logs:/var/log/gitlab 
  --volume $env:GITLAB_HOME/data:/var/opt/gitlab 
  --shm-size 256m 
  gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest
```

The creation of the container worked. Now I can reach gitlab in the browser via http://192.168.178.35.

Unfortunately https does not work. When I enter https://192.168.178.35 in my brwoser, it shows there the following error message:

```
Error: Secure connection failed.
```

Can someone help me and tell me what I need to do to set up access via https?

Answer (score 1):

Try first with  `gitlab/gitlab-ce:15.4.0-ce.0`, the community edition, instead of `gitlab-ee` (Enterprise edition)
And using a fixed label (`15.4.0-ce.0`), you will have less surprise if one day '`latest`' changes.

Second check the "[GitLab is unreachable in my browser](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/troubleshooting.html#gitlab-is-unreachable-in-my-browser)" section, which mentions the firewall for possible root cause.

Comment: where can I find an overview of the current versions. When I type `docker search gitlab`, no versions are displayed.